# question about port

Tags: c#, serial-port

i have a problem
i am writing a code in C# 
i wanna receive a byte from serial port 
but when i wanna receive data from port that sounds my program is hang
and doesnt work  any more

```
 SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3");
 port.Open();
 byte[] b = new byte[10];
 port.Read(b, 0, 1);
 port.Close();
```

please help me

Comment: SerialPort.Read() won't return unless there are bytes to be read.  Are you sure that something is writing to the port?  Usually it's best to use something like Hyperterminal to verify that the port has the data you expect.

Comment: Not setting the baudrate, not turning on the handshake lines.  Yeah, that will block.

Answer (score 1):

This is because SerialPort reads data synchronously and blocks current thread until the data would be available.

You can use separate thread for this:

```
public class SerialPort : IDisposable
{
    public SerialPort(byte comNum, int baudRate)
    {
        this.comNum = comNum;
        serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM" + comNum.ToString(), baudRate);
        serialPort.Open();
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(ThreadFn);
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (thread != null)
           thread.Abort();
        if (serialPort != null)
           serialPort.Dispose();
    }

    private void OnReceiveByte(byte b)
    {
        //handle received byte
    }

    private void ThreadFn(object obj)
    {
        Byte[] inputBuffer = new Byte[inputBufferSize];
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                int availibleBytes = serialPort.BytesToRead;
                if (availibleBytes > 0)
                {
                    int bytesToRead = availibleBytes < inputBufferSize ? availibleBytes : inputBufferSize;
                    int readedBytes = serialPort.Read(inputBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                    for (int i = 0; i < readedBytes; i++)
                        OnReceiveByte(inputBuffer[i]);
                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false, e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    private Byte comNum;
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort;
    private System.Threading.Thread thread;
    private const int inputBufferSize = 1024;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually any data being sent over the serial port? The call to Read might just be waiting to receive some data before returning. Make sure that you have set a value for the ReadTimeout property. This will make the call to Read throw a TimeoutException if no data was read from the port.

Reference:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you set the serial speed right (if you're reading too fast you'll miss some data, etc)